# Xfce - minimizing windows to tray (iconifying)

Tags: linux, icons, xfce, desktop-environments

For XFCE (v. 4.8), I'm searching for possible options to minimize windows to tray (iconify). This means that 1) they're not in the window listing and 2) they're not in the alt+TAB menu and 3) when closed OR minimized, the window hides (it disappears from window listing but still stays running).

- **alltray** has some weird GTK-related bug ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/alltray/+bug/589831; windows hide but unhiding doesn't do anything; they stay in the tray icon until the user undocks them ) -- version 0.7.4dev+ has this fixed, but 1) when clicking 'X', it closes window instead of hiding it; 2) when minimizing, window stays in the taskbar; 3) there is no way to hide the window other than by clicking the icon (see item 3 of the first paragraph).
- **trayer** complains that "another systray is already running" and if I remove the original 'notification area' where all the tray icons usually appear, then trayer would start over the screen bottom, overlaying over the existing bottom panel without an option of adding self to any existing panel as a new item.
- **kdocker** works unreliably as some clicks unhide the window and then instantly hide it again; it also does not appear to be able to iconify a window when closed (it actually closed instead -- see item 3 of the first paragraph in this question).
- **docker** creates a new systay at the left top of the screen and erases everything in the 'notification area' applet, so the things don't get restored after pkill'ing *docker*; the *docker* item overlaps on the existing panel and occupies a part of screen making it unusable; the *docker* item is only one icon wide and doesn't scroll.

What I want to iconify is *xfce4-terminal*, so any terminal which can iconify itself and works with xfce would be ok as a solution, too.

This question here is to ask about possible minimalistic (as everything in XFCE is) solutions  which don't involve manual compiling, and aren't an overkill like **cairo-dock** is ( a rather bloated gnome-style application which creates a new large 'tray' instead of using the existing one ). Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the window buttons panel plugin? With the right options (such as "included iconified windows" (or not) in the window manager tweaks settings I think it can already do what you seem to be asking.

Comment: I don't see how to use the window buttons panel plugin to iconify windows. If it can do that, please do reply with details on this possible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> kdocker ... it also does not appear to be able to iconify a window
>   when closed (it actually closed instead).

As far as I understand no docker can do that. This has to be supported
by the application (e.g. claws, vlc, etc). When you click on close the
window manager signals the application to close, depending on its setup
it closes or minimises to tray.

> What I want to iconify is xfce4-terminal, so any terminal which can
>   iconify itself and works with xfce would be ok as a solution, too.

I don't have an exact solution to this, but in terms of how it appears
in window or Alt-Tab lists its identical. You could use a drop down
terminal like [guake](http://guake.org/). It lets you define a hotkey
that will make the terminal appear and disappear. You can also add some
window events as triggers for it to disappear (e.g. some other window
raises itself). You can also configure other how and where it appears,
what size it has. I like the fact that the terminal is always at the
same place no matter when I call it and its always running at login.

The only missing feature I have found is, I can't control which display
it appears on for dual display setups; it always uses the left most
display.

Comment: so, you have no solution, yet you answer the question...